# How to prove or disprove that $T(X_{1},X_{2}) = X_{1} + X_{2}$ is a sufficient statistic

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution, sufficient-statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ be random sample from a population whose distribution is given by $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$, $0 < \theta < 1$.

a. Show that $T(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

b. In the same context, consider that $T = X_{1} + X_{2}$. What is the distribution of $T$? Is $T$ a sufficient statistic?

**MY ATTEMPT**

a. To begin with, let us determine the likelihood function for this sample
\begin{align*}
L(\textbf{x}|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}\theta^{x_{i}}(1-\theta)^{1-x_{i}} = \theta^{\sum x_{i}}(1-\theta)^{n - \sum x_{i}} = h(\textbf{x})g_{\theta}(T(\textbf{x}))
\end{align*}

Therefore, according to the factorization theorem, $T(\textbf{x})$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

b. As it is known, the sum of independent Bernoulli random variables is a Binomial random variable. Therefore $T = X_{1} + X_{2} \sim \text{Binomial}(2,\theta)$.

Then I get stuck. Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (a) trivially implies the answer to the second part of (b) by setting $n=2.$

Comment: On the other hand, if $n>2$ then the answer by @Vishaal answer is helpful. I think this may be the intention of the question, but it is unclear with the information you have given us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to show is that $$P(X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,...X_n=x_n|X_1+X_2 = t )$$ depends on $\theta$ to prove that $T=X_1+X_2$ is NOT a sufficient statistic.

Comment: Could you explain what part of the question this answers and why it answers it?

Comment: @Whuber I have answered "Is $X_1 + X_2$ sufficient?" ... That was the last question where the OP got stuck. I interpreted the question like this, out of a random sample following bernoulli($\theta$)of size N if we know the sum of the first 2 random variables does it contain sufficient information about the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: Unfortunately, that answer is wrong.  It contradicts the answer to question (1).

Comment: According to me.. Question(1) is whether sum of all samples is sufficient of not. Question(2) is, In the presence of N samples, whether the sum of first 2 sufficient or not. I've updated my answer. Please check it once more.

Comment: Suppose you have the $n$ data as in question (1) but you have observed only the first $2$ of them so far.  Your answer asserts this is not enough information to estimate $\theta.$  But if $n=2,$ question (1) asserts it *is* enough.  That's a contradiction.  How do you resolve it?

Comment: In that case you're correct. But I understood the question as we have already observed n samples, now before discarding the sample we would like to compute a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, so is $X_1 +X_2$ a sufficient statistic?. I interpreted the question in this way because in Question(2) it says "In the same context" so I assumed the OP wants to say all n samples have been observed like it has been observed for Question(1).

Comment: If you're unsure, then the right approach is to apply the definition of sufficient statistic.  That will help you answer correctly.